# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo cannot be cast to android.widget.ZoomControls

Tags: android, eclipse, classcastexception

I'm new to android development, hope you all can help me. I got this androidVNC viewer source code from internet. When i'm running the androidVNC application in the emulator, it will exit automatically then i get following errors in LogCat. Can anyone one help me? Thanks.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{android.androidVNC/android.androidVNC.VncCanvasActivity}:       java.lang.ClassCastException: com.antlersoft.android.zoomer.ZoomControls cannot be cast to     android.widget.ZoomControls
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.antlersoft.android.zoomer.ZoomControls       cannot be cast to android.widget.ZoomControls
at android.androidVNC.VncCanvasActivity.onCreate(VncCanvasActivity.java:585)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
... 11 more
```

This is the ZoomControls java file:

```
package com.antlersoft.android.zoomer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ZoomButton;


public class ZoomControls extends LinearLayout {

private final ZoomButton mZoomIn;
private final ZoomButton mZoomOut;
private final ImageButton mZoomKeyboard;

public ZoomControls(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public ZoomControls(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setFocusable(false);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.zoom_controls, this, // we are the parent
            true);

    mZoomIn = (ZoomButton) findViewById(R.id.zoomIn);
    mZoomOut = (ZoomButton) findViewById(R.id.zoomOut);
    mZoomKeyboard = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.zoomKeys);
}

public void setOnZoomInClickListener(OnClickListener listener) {
    mZoomIn.setOnClickListener(listener);
}

public void setOnZoomOutClickListener(OnClickListener listener) {
    mZoomOut.setOnClickListener(listener);
}

public void setOnZoomKeyboardClickListener(OnClickListener listener) {
    mZoomKeyboard.setOnClickListener(listener);
}

/*
 * Sets how fast you get zoom events when the user holds down the
 * zoom in/out buttons.
 */
public void setZoomSpeed(long speed) {
    mZoomIn.setZoomSpeed(speed);
    mZoomOut.setZoomSpeed(speed);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    /* Consume all touch events so they don't get dispatched to the view
     * beneath this view.
     */
    return true;
}

public void show() {
    fade(View.VISIBLE, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}

public void hide() {
    fade(View.GONE, 1.0f, 0.0f);
}

private void fade(int visibility, float startAlpha, float endAlpha) {
    AlphaAnimation anim = new AlphaAnimation(startAlpha, endAlpha);
    anim.setDuration(500);
    startAnimation(anim);
    setVisibility(visibility);
}

public void setIsZoomInEnabled(boolean isEnabled) {
    mZoomIn.setEnabled(isEnabled);
}

public void setIsZoomOutEnabled(boolean isEnabled) {
    mZoomOut.setEnabled(isEnabled);
}

@Override
public boolean hasFocus() {
    return mZoomIn.hasFocus() || mZoomOut.hasFocus();
}
```

}

This is the zoom_controls XML file:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ZoomButton android:id="@+id/zoomOut" 
    android:background="@drawable/btn_zoom_down" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/zoomKeys"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_dialer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<ZoomButton android:id="@+id/zoomIn" 
    android:background="@drawable/btn_zoom_up"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</merge>
```

Comment: may be some code help us to find the problem. But error is clear you are casting `com.antlersoft.android.zoomer.ZoomControls` into `android.widget.ZoomControls`

Comment: @AliImran why? It is same what I wrote in comment!

Comment: sorry,can you further explain it?

Comment: I guess in `VncCanvasActivity.java` you have this import `android.widget.ZoomControls` change this with `import com.antlersoft.android.zoomer.ZoomControls` as @AliImran suggest.

Comment: You should accept the answer if it is the correct one :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong `import` use this `com.antlersoft.android.zoomer.ZoomControls` instead of `android.widget.ZoomControls`